# SQL Group By and sum of other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

following is raw table

```
+--------------+---------------+----------+---------+-----------+
| CustomerName | InvoiceNumber | ItemRate | TaxRate | TaxAmount |
+--------------+---------------+----------+---------+-----------+
| A            |             1 |      500 | 4%      | 20        |
| B            |             2 |      300 | 9%      | 27        |
| B            |             2 |      100 | 9%      | 9         |
| B            |             2 |      400 | 4%      | 16        |
| C            |             3 |      250 | 9%      | 22.5      |
| C            |             3 |      650 | 4%      | 26        |
| D            |             4 |      200 | 4%      | 8         |
| D            |             4 |      100 | 4%      | 4         |
+--------------+---------------+----------+---------+-----------+
```

---

I want output like this:

```
+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------+
| CustomerName | InvoiceNumber | InvoiceTotal | TaxRate | TaxAmount |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------+
| A            |             1 |          500 | 4%      | 20        |
| B            |             2 |          800 | 9%      | 36        |
| B            |             2 |          800 | 4%      | 16        |
| C            |             3 |          900 | 9%      | 22.5      |
| C            |             3 |          900 | 4%      | 26        |
| D            |             4 |          300 | 4%      | 12        |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------+
```

I am having issue with sum of Invoice value when doing Group By.
I have to do group by with "TaxRate" to combine similar Taxes and along with it i want to include new column in result which shows Total for that perticular Invoice.

Invoice Total column should have sum of entire invoice, where as my current query is summing Total by tax group and not by entire invoice.

my query is:

```
Select CustomerName, InvoiceNumber, sum(itemrate) as InvoiceTotal, TaxRate, sum(TaxAmount) 
from salestable group by customername,invoicenumber, Taxrate
```

Please help to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you include your attempt(s) please? It's difficult for us to tell you where you went wrong, when we don't have your SQL.

Comment: i updated my question, see "my query is:" part in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to sum `itemrate` over the invoice for each customer:

```
select CustomerName, InvoiceNumber,
       sum(sum(itemrate)) over (partition by CustomerName, InvoiceNumber) as InvoiceTotal,
       TaxRate,
       sum(TaxAmount) as TaxAmount
from salestable
group by customername, invoicenumber, Taxrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT CustomerName,SUM(ItemRate)  InvoiceTotal
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY CustomerName
)

SELECT A.CustomerName,A.InvoiceNumber,B.InvoiceTotal,A.TaxRate,SUM(A.TaxAmount)
FROM your_table A
LEFT JOIN CTE B ON A.CustomerName = B.CustomerName
GROUP BY A.CustomerName,A.InvoiceNumber,B.InvoiceTotal,A.TaxRate
ORDER BY A.CustomerName,A.TaxRate DESC
```

Comment: DV almost before I post ;)

Comment: Why though? This works (although the `TaxRate` is in the reverse order)

Comment: ORDER BY added :) @Martin

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT  tab.CustomerName,
        tab.InvoiceNumber,
        it.InvoiceTotal,
        tab.TaxRate,
        SUM(tab.TaxAmount) AS TaxAmount
  FROM tab
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT InvoiceNumber, SUM(ItemRate) AS InvoiceTotal FROM tab GROUP BY InvoiceNumber
               ) it ON it.InvoiceNumber = tab.InvoiceNumber
  GROUP BY tab.CustomerName, tab.InvoiceNumber, it.InvoiceTotal, tab.TaxRate
  ORDER BY tab.CustomerName, tab.TaxRate DESC
```

See the associated [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7f359/1).

Results:

```
A   1   500 4   20
B   2   800 9   36
B   2   800 4   16
C   3   900 9   22.5
C   3   900 4   26
D   4   300 4   12
```